# ElasticSearch: No field found for [" + field + "] in groovy script

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm performing this groovy script in my elasticsearch instance. This is the content of a groovy script located in `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/scripts`:

```
def opDate = new DateTime(doc['" + field + "'].date);opDate.getYear();
```

It's reached and ES is trying to perform it, nevertheless it's telling me:

```
No field found for [" + field + "] in mapping with types [fuas]
```

This is the Java code I send to ES:

```
AggregationBuilders
    .terms(this.getName())
    .field(this.getName())
    .script(
        new Script(
            "year",
            ScriptType.FILE,
            "groovy",
            ImmutableMap.of("field", this.getName())
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few too many quotes in there. Modify your script like this (`field` is a parameter to your script):

```
def opDate = new DateTime(doc[field].date);opDate.getYear();
```